# how to modify existing object by formset

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Product Model like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   title = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

and a Image Model like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=....)
```

Now, I can add a product with multiple image by formset, but what should I do to modify existing product. In server-side code, I need to know which image be modified, which image is new added, which image be deleted. Of course, I can to do it by normal way, just like if I delete a image, I will change it's name to "delete-img_id" through javascript, if I modify a image, I can change it's name to "modify-img_id", then check it in django server-side and handle them with correctly operate, like this:

```
def check_img(name):
   operate = name.split("-")[0]
   img_id = name.slipt("-")[1]
   if operate == "modify": modify_img(img_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override `save_formset` method of ModelAdmin

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    if formset and formset.has_changed():
        quiz_obj = formset.save(commit=False)[0].product
        # todo 
    return super(ProductAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```